# How can i get a list of all MUC 's in XMPP server using python xmpppy?

Tags: python, xmpp, service-discovery, xmpppy

I need to get a list of MUC's in a XMPP server (OpenFire). I have read about XEP 0030 and service discovery, but can not find documentation or examples about implementing it with xmpppy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in `xmpp/features.py`, and try code like this:

```
for i in discoverItems(conn, jid.getDomain()):
    (ids, features) = discoverInfo(conn, i.jid)
    if NS_MUC in features:
        print i.jid
```

(warning: completely untested)

Comment: Thank you very much !!!  It worked.  I had to replace jid.getdomain() with the name of the service, in my case  conference.servername and I get a dictionary - i with keys - jid, name .